# mosquitto_pub gives the following error: 1408F10B: SSL routines: ssl3_get_record: wrong version number

Tags: openssl, mqtt, lets-encrypt, mosquitto

I've configured mosquitto to listen on port 8883, and generated letsencrypt SSL certificates for the server. So far so good.

I can successfully test the TLS connection:
`openssl s_client -connect mqtt.example.com:8883` gives me the certificate and session info, and mosquitto's logs report a successful connection.

I can also successfully publish a message using the paho python library.

However, when I try with `mosquitto_pub` it does this:

```
$ mosquitto_pub -h mqtt.example.com -p 8883 -u foobar -P "" -t foobar -m test
Client connection from XX.XX.XX.XX failed: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number.
```

This seems to be a common problem, but none of the solutions I've found searching the web seem to apply to me because they generally involve the client identifying itself using a  [self-signed certificate](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-tls-7.html).

So I'm stumped. Does anyone know what's causing this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get `mosquitto_pub` to attempt to start a SSL connection you need to provide either `--cafile` or `--capath` that points to the location of the CA certificates to verify the broker.

Without these options neither `mosquitto_pub` or `mosquitto_sub` will not attempt to start a SSL session and instead try and connect with a normal unencrypted MQTT connection.

On most Linux distributions you can use `--capath` and point to `/etc/ssl/certs` directory

Comment: Ah, thanks, I didn't realize that `mosquitto_pub` didn't trust certificates by default.

Comment: Lifesaver. I didn't realize capath was needed because I thought it was for self-signed certs and the client would accept letsencrypt as a "not self-signed = globally trusted" CA. I didn't realize that it needs a list of trusted CAs in the first place and /etc/ssl/certs is precisely this. The linux distro comes with a list of trusted CAs and it is so transparent that I came to forget about it.

Answer (score -1):

For me the only solution I found was to revert to mosquitto 1.5

Comment: The behaviour described and that in the accepted answer would not change at version 1.5 (which was last updated in sept 2019) and any of the much newer versions. Also there is no where near enough context in this answer to be useful, you've not said what other versions you tried or how.